Animate strikethrough for anchor tag without losing focus
I'm trying to create an animation where line-through will go from left to right on hover, But I'm not able to achieve it. As there are some limitations with the text-decoration property.
So I tried with pseudo-elements like ::after& gradient but the problem is my anchor tag stacks above and if I use z-index to manage that, I lose the focus from the anchor tag and I'm not able to click on the anchor tag
And for the pseudo-elements, it's not working with multiple lines.
Attempt using text-decoration properties:


span {
  text-decoration: line-through !important;
  text-decoration-color: transparent !important;
  transition: text-decoration-color 1s;
}

span:hover {
  text-decoration: line-through !important;
  text-decoration-color: red !important;
}
<span><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</a></span>



Attempt using a gradient:


span {
  background: linear-gradient(red 0 0) no-repeat 0 60% / var(--s, 0%) .1em, #000;
  -webkit-background-clip: border-box, text;
  background-clip: border-box, text;
  color: #0000;
  transition: background-size .4s ease;
  font-size: 1.9em;
}

span:hover {
  --s: 100%;
}
<span><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</a></span>



Attempt using pseudo-elements:


.strikethrough-animation {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.strikethrough-animation::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px; /* Adjust thickness of the line */
  background-color: black; /* Adjust color of the line */
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left center;
  transition: transform 1s ease; /* Adjust duration and timing function */
}

.strikethrough-animation:hover::after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
<span>
  <a class="strikethrough-animation"  href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</a>
</span>




It seems like your gradient approach is working well. What's the issue with it?

@Sean The strikethrough is going below in the stacking

With the absolute positioning, that is causing issues with the shape of the pseudo element not following the actual inline text flow any more. I think the gradient approach, slightly modified (see my answer) will probably work best.

@mr.Hritik so you asked the question from the question?

Turn it around - put the span into the a, then you can use z-index to get the text behind the background of the link. And no background clipping any more, but simply a gradient that is transparent in all but the red part.


a {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(red 0 0) no-repeat 
    0 60% / var(--s,0%) .1em,
    #0000;
  color: #000;
  transition: background-size .4s ease;
  font-size: 1.9em;
}
a:hover {
  --s: 100%;
}
a span { position: relative; z-index:-1; }
<a href="#"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</span></a>




What was the issue with the previous code , Due to block element into inline-block element?

Are you asking about your own "Attempt using pseudo-elements" snippet from above now? That pseudo element won't follow the text flow across multiple lines, because it is positioned absolute.

Talking about gradient

That had multiple issues, the order (background can't come in front of element content, unless you mess around with z-indexes, which did not work with the given HTML structure) being one of them.

just for your information, he simply copied your answer to answer another question with 0 credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78345411/8620333 (already flagged his other answer)
